# Why is xdebug not showing up in phpinfo()

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

I am trying to get the following to setup work:

- Windows 7 - 64-bit
- XAMPP 1.7.4
- XDebug  [php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc9-x86_64.dll]

When I run phpinfo() from Xampps homepage, XDebug it is not listed anywhere. I checked the Apache error logs and there are no errors, so it seems to load the module without problem? I haven't used PHP in years so I have no clue why this isn't working.

```
[PHP.ini]

[XDebug]
zend_extension_ts = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc9-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you don't have the right compiler version. Copy the output of your phpinfo onto [this](http://www.xdebug.org/find-binary.php) page and it will tell you which version you need.

Comment: I was using the wrong compiler and was using the wrong zend_extension. Needed to write it without _ts. Awesome link thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Print out your

> phpinfo();

and look at "Compilater" line

At home (win7x64 + wamp) => MSVC6 (Visual C++ 6.0)

So you need the [vc6](http://www.xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll) version not vc9 version

Comment: Thanks, that was part of the problem